# How to get spinner to disappear once url loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

[image]I have created a small program with a spinner. Once the url completely loads in the iframe, then the spinner is supposed to disapear. I can get the page to load but I cannot get the spinner to disappear.

Here is my javascript code(I am not sure if the style.display='none' line is valid:

```
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
    })
```

Here is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Spinner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="overlay">
    <div class="spinner"></div> 
    </div>

    <iframe width="1120" height="630" src="https://tommcfarlin.com/check-if-        a-page-is-in-an-iframe/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
   body{
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.spinner{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;

border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
border-top:3px solid #f25a41;
border-radius: 100%;

position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;

animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
from{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}to{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}

#overlay{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
}
```

I think my issue is in the Javascript but please correct me if I am wrong here.
I have also included a screen print showing that the page is loaded in the background but the spinner is still there.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where do you added your javascript file to your html file, didn't you forgot to add the script to your html code? `<script src="..."></script>`

Comment: Does the `window.addEventListener('load')` callback ever get invoked?

Comment: @AlanFriedman  I don't believe it does. I wanted to see if this is still valid.

Comment: @Azhy What exactly would I put in the html code?

Comment: Try replacing the load event callback with a `setTimeout` of a few seconds to test if it works.

Comment: If you didn't add your script to your html code just add this code into html head element `<Script src="javascriptFilePath.js"></Script>`

Comment: @AlanFriedman Yeah the setTimeout did not work also.

Comment: @Azhy just added that and that also did not change anything. I wonder if it is reading the javascript

Comment: I added <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> to the end of the body in the html and that did the trick also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script didn't load to your html code so try to change your html code to that code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spinner</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
overlay.style.display = 'none';
};
<script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="overlay">
<div class="spinner"></div> 
</div>

<iframe width="1120" height="630" 
src="https://tommcfarlin.com/check-if-        a-page-is-in- 
an-iframe/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result. I wonder if this line is correct window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  overlay.style.display = 'none';
})

Comment: I made some letter errors, i edited so copy it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is fine. I am not sure what the exact error is I tried the same on my pc and it seems to work fine. I would suggest you put your script just before the end of body tag or after the end of the overlay div because HTML loads and parses by line, if JS does not find your overlay div it throws an exception and the code breaks.